# Transform failed

Tags: navigation, transforms, hector, tf2, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I have a simple tf-tree (sorry, i have not enough point to download picture). May be it is available [here](http://hkar.ru/CjCu).

If no: tf-tree is **map -> odom -> base_link -> lazer**.
When i launch file with gmapping, not always there is an error:

> Transform failed during publishing of map_odom transform: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1436451359.820962500 but the latest data is at time 1436451359.720510500, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom].

It happens not always. But when after this file i launch the other contais **hector_exploration_node**, **hector_exploration_planner** and **hector_costmap**, it happens every time.

I changed the **use_sim_time** parameter: if it is *false*, there is the error, else there isn't error, but the navigation part(second launch file) only starts and doesn't work (freezes).
I did [this](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) diagnostic. It works properly.

**Edit:**

> Fist launch file:
>
> ```
> <!-- Costmap parameters -->
> <param name="use_elevation_map" value="false" />
> <param name="use_grid_map" value="true" />
> <param name="use_cloud_map" value="false" />
>
> <param name="initial_free_cells_radius"
> ```
>
> value="0.3" />

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213279/transform-failed/) by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-10**:
does this only happen at the very beginning, when you launch the nodes? Are also concurrently?
If it is just at the beginning, it might be because the oldest `/odom->/base_link` transform is about 100ms older than the oldest `/map->/odom` transform.

**Comment by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on 2015-07-10**:
Before second launch first lunch work properly, but after launch them (nodes with navigation), it (first launch)  started issue the errors unceasingly.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-10**:
please edit your answer with the order in which you start which launchfiles. also please include the launch files.

**Comment by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on 2015-07-10**:
Sorry, i wasn't able to issue launch files carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should put these lines to your code:
1
odom

---

Originally posted by [smostafa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29312/smostafa/) with karma: 16 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0